# Handling unhandled exceptions in .Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am doing a application level exception handling in .NetCore 2.2. But facing some issue

So in my startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/GlobalException");
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/GlobalException");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    //app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseSession();
    //app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleware>();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Account}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });            
}
```

And ExceptionController.cs is

```
public class ExceptionController : Controller
{
    [Route("Error/{statusCode}")]
    public IActionResult HttpStatusCodeHandler(int statusCode)
    {
        var statusCodeResult = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();
        switch (statusCode)
        {
            case 404:
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Sorry, the resource you requested could not be found";
                break;
            default:
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Sorry, the resource you requested could not be found";
                break;
        }
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("GlobalException")]
    public IActionResult GlobalException()
    {
        var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
        var exceptionPath = exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Path;
        var exceptionMessage = exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error.Message;
        var exceptionStackTrace = exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error.StackTrace;
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Sorry, the resource you requested could not be found";

        //return await HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("he"));
        //return View("GlobalException");//"~/Views/Shared/HttpStatusCodeHandler.cshtml"
        return View("~/Views/Exception/GlobalException.cshtml");
    }
}
```

AuthenticationMiddleware.cs

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    bool isAjaxCall = context.Request.Headers["x-requested-with"] == "XMLHttpRequest";

    if(isAjaxCall)
    {
        // someAjax related functionality.
    }
    else if (!context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/account/Index"))
    {
        if (context.Session.Keys.Contains("UserName"))
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/account/Index");
        }
    }
    else if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/GlobalException"))
    {
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
    await _next.Invoke(context);
}
```

I am able to navigate to all the exception page when I receive 404,and other errors. 
But when any run time exception is arised in the application. GlobalException() is being executed but in UI, It not navigating that View.

Trying to raise an exception for testing purpose

```
public ActionResult RaiseException()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Could anyone please help me with this as I am struggling since two days.
Please provide me a better approach if possible. Thank you.

Comment: How will GlobalException() be executed but in UI, It not navigating to  GlobalException View? I test the code in local and it works well.Besides, I do not know what is the use of  `AuthenticationMiddleware`?

Comment: Are you sure about your current environment ?